# Selective Product Category for Carousel

Tags: functions, woocommerce-offtopic, wp-admin, templates

I am trying to pull product images that are assigned to a monthly-special product category. I tried 'category_name' => 'monthly-specials' and it does not appear to work correctly. Can anyone shed some light on what I did wrong and how to select a specific product category that the product is assigned to for the homepage?

```
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme f-products">
      <?php
      $args = array(
      'post_type' => 'product',
        'category_name' => 'monthly-specials',
      'stock' => 1,
      'posts_per_page' => 12,
      'orderby' =>'date',
      'order' => 'DESC' );
      $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
      while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product; ?>
      <div class="item">
      <a id="id-<?php the_id(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
      <?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $loop->post->ID )) echo get_the_post_thumbnail($loop->post->ID, 'shop_catalog'); else echo '<img src="'.woocommerce_placeholder_img_src().'" alt="My Image Placeholder" width="65px" height="115px" />'; ?>
      <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
        </a>
        <div class="item-footer">
      <span class="price"><?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?></span>
      <span><?php woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart( $loop->post, $product ); ?></span>
    </div>
      </div><!-- /span3 -->
      <?php endwhile; ?>
      <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these products came from WooCommerce, then most probably you’re using wrong taxonomy in your code.

WC products use product_cat taxonomy as categories, so you can’t use built-in categories to filter them.

Use this instead

```
 'product_cat' => 'category-slug-here',
```

and it should work correctly.

Comment: @WilliamJerome No problem :)